# Bypassing navigation loop

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

If I have Navigation made like this:

```
Home -> Process -> Add a thing -> Success
```

and from `Success` Page you can start process again. Let's say you're doing this 20 times and then you're clicking back button. You will be backing through all 20 processes made. starting a new process with `clearHistory: true` will remove back button from `Process` page. Is there a clean way to fix this and make Process back button go to `Home`?

Comment: in the `success` page, navigate to `process` and use `clearHistory: true` like you mentioned

Comment: you could also write code to cancel the back button default behaviour and do some navigation instead.

Comment: @FlorianThuin setting back button tap event doesn't fix the swipe-back problem

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I'm sorry but this doesn't fix the problem

Comment: @Tukkan why not? could you please elaborate on the issue?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon because we will go to Process page with clean back history but we still want the ability to go back to Home.

Comment: why not add a custom back button then? that navigates to the home page?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon because swipe-back on iOS will still will be broken. Same with Android hardware back button.

Comment: you can disable the back button on android, and the clear history will help on ios, or it should

Comment: @mast3rd3mon clear history makes history empty so swipe-back will be disabled. Disabling of this ability is not the fix of the problem.

Comment: it wont be disabled, it will swipe to the previous page in the history

Comment: @mast3rd3mon how if history is empty because we passed clearHistory: true? :)

Comment: clear history removes the current page in the navigation stack

Comment: @mast3rd3mon you confused replaceUrl with clearHistory. replaceUrl is not available in NativeScript, clearHistory clears whole history. I'm 100% sure.

Comment: @mast3rd3mon from Nativescript docs: `Set the clearHistory property of the NavigationEntry to true. This will prevent the user from going back to pages previously visited.`

Comment: in which case, i have found a bug because thats not how it behaves in any of my apps

Comment: @mast3rd3mon any time you do this.routerExtensions.navigate(['path'], { clearHistory: true}). Back button of navigated page on iOS will be hidden because there is no history.

Comment: i rarely use ios so i havent experienced that

Comment: @mast3rd3mon on Android, if you clear history, using hardware back button by default closes the app. In that case you can handle this event and write logic for that case. It's not handy anyways. For iOS this is not the case because it's even harder.

Comment: `on Android, if you clear history, using hardware back button by default closes the app` not in any app that i have written have i experienced this, it always removes the last/current page from the stack

Comment: @mast3rd3mon it's not random behaviour. If it sometimes behaves differently in your apps, you had to change behaviour of hardware back button :)

Comment: as i have stated, _from my own experience with apps_, it does only remove the last item. i am not arguing against what _should_ happen, only what _does_ happen

Comment: @mast3rd3mon ok, so I would consider it as a bug in the framework if somehow it works like that on your side :) Anyhow thanks for your input!

Answer (score -1):

You could use **`backstackVisible`** boolean property - documentation example [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/navigation#navigate-without-history). When navigation with the property set to `false` the entry won't become a part of the navigation stack and as a result, the backward navigation will skip this page. API reference [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/interfaces/_ui_frame_.navigationentry#backstackvisible).

**Note:** This property is currently supported only in **[NativeScript Core](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/navigation)** (won't work in Angular based project)

Comment: Can we mix Core and Angular somehow? I bet that most people use Nativescript Angular.

Comment: No if we are talking about navigation - The routing API is different in Angular so take a look at the navigation article for Angular based applications https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/angular-navigation

Comment: In Angular, you could also use router-outlet to prevent going back using the hardware button. Or as an alternative idea, you could use fullscreen modal pages https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/dialogs#custom-dialog

Comment: I was thinking about router-outlet but this removes the native feel. You cannot swipe-back and there is no animation. I also read the article about routing. I bet there is no solution for my problem in nativescript-angular

Comment: @Tukkan Were you able to find a work around for not storing a specific router redirect in history?